# GNAudioSourceMic raw audio location

Tags: ios, audio, gracenote, audio-fingerprinting

I'm currently developing an app which uses Gracenote Mobile Client to create a fingerprint as well as identify which music I'm listening to. I've successfully implemented it on my project but now due to a business requirement I've to use the audio recorded by Gracenote for a different processing.

The point is: As GNAudioSourceMic encapsulates the whole microphone recording operations such as startRecording/stopRecording so I've no access to Microphone raw audio.

This is the code I'm using:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
    [self setupUI];

    @try {
        self.config = [GNConfig init:GRACENOTE_CLIENTID];
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"%s clientId can't be nil or the empty string",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
        [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:FALSE];
        return;
    }

    // Debug is disabled in the GUI by default
#ifdef DEBUG
    [self.config setProperty:@"debugEnabled" value:@"1"];
#else
    [self.config setProperty:@"debugEnabled" value:@"0"];
#endif
    [self.config setProperty:@"lookupmodelocalonly" value:@"0"];

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Init AudioSource to Start Recording.
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    self.recognizeFromPCM = [GNRecognizeStream gNRecognizeStream:self.config];
    self.audioConfig = [GNAudioConfig gNAudioConfigWithSampleRate:44100 bytesPerSample:2 numChannels:1];

    self.objAudioSource = [GNAudioSourceMic gNAudioSourceMic:self.audioConfig];
    self.objAudioSource.delegate=self;

    NSError *err;

    RecognizeStreamOperation *op = [RecognizeStreamOperation recognizeStreamOperation:self.config];
    op.viewControllerDelegate = self;
    err = [self.recognizeFromPCM startRecognizeSession:op audioConfig:self.audioConfig];

    if (err) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: %@",[err localizedDescription]);
    }

    [self.objAudioSource startRecording];

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setUpRecognizePCMSession) withObject:nil];

}

-(void) startRecordMicrophone{
    #ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog(@"%s startRecording",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    #endif

    NSError *error;
    error = [self.recognizeFromPCM idNow];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
    }

}
```

Does someone have been exposed to the same need as explained above ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much googling yesterday I came up with a solution which isn't what I was previously expecting but it works as good as I want to. I've decided to record the iOS microphone myself and then call a method on Grancenote SDK to recognise what I've just recorded.

Here's what has worked for me.

**MicrophoneInput.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface MicrophoneInput : UIViewController {
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
    AVAudioRecorder *audioRecorder;
    int recordEncoding;
    enum
    {
        ENC_AAC = 1,
        ENC_ALAC = 2,
        ENC_IMA4 = 3,
        ENC_ILBC = 4,
        ENC_ULAW = 5,
        ENC_PCM = 6,
    } encodingTypes;
}

-(IBAction) startRecording;
-(IBAction) stopRecording;

@end
```

**MicrophoneInput.m**

```
#import "MicrophoneInput.h"


@implementation MicrophoneInput

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    recordEncoding = ENC_PCM;
}

-(IBAction) startRecording
{
    NSLog(@"startRecording");
    [audioRecorder release];
    audioRecorder = nil;

    // Init audio with record capability
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];

    NSMutableDictionary *recordSettings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
    recordSettings[AVFormatIDKey] = @(kAudioFormatLinearPCM);
    recordSettings[AVSampleRateKey] = @8000.0f;
    recordSettings[AVNumberOfChannelsKey] = @1;
    recordSettings[AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey] = @16;
    recordSettings[AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey] = @NO;
    recordSettings[AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey] = @NO;   

    //set the export session's outputURL to <Documents>/output.caf
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = paths[0];
    NSURL* outURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"output.caf"]];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:outURL error:nil];
    NSLog(@"url loc is %@", outURL);

    NSError *error = nil;
    audioRecorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outURL settings:recordSettings error:&error];

    if ([audioRecorder prepareToRecord] == YES){
        [audioRecorder record];
    }else {
        int errorCode = CFSwapInt32HostToBig ([error code]); 
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ [%4.4s])" , [error localizedDescription], (char*)&errorCode); 

    }
    NSLog(@"recording");
}

-(IBAction) stopRecording
{
    NSLog(@"stopRecording");
    [audioRecorder stop];
    NSLog(@"stopped");
}


- (void)dealloc
{
    [audioPlayer release];
    [audioRecorder release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Obs.: If you're using ARC don't forget to add -fno-objc-arc compiler flag on Compiling BuildPhase as shown below.

[image]

**YourViewController.h**

```
//Libraries
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

//Echonest Codegen
#import "MicrophoneInput.h"

//GracenoteMusic
#import <GracenoteMusicID/GNRecognizeStream.h>
#import <GracenoteMusicID/GNAudioSourceMic.h>
#import <GracenoteMusicID/GNAudioConfig.h>
#import <GracenoteMusicID/GNCacheStatus.h>
#import <GracenoteMusicID/GNConfig.h>
#import <GracenoteMusicID/GNSampleBuffer.h>
#import <GracenoteMusicID/GNOperations.h>
#import <GracenoteMusicID/GNSearchResponse.h>

@interface YourViewController : UIViewController<GNSearchResultReady>


@end
```

**YourViewController.m**

```
#import "YourViewController.h"

@interface YourViewController ()
//Record
@property(strong,nonatomic) MicrophoneInput* recorder;
@property (strong,nonatomic) GNConfig *config;
@end

@implementation YourViewController


#pragma mark - UIViewController lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.recorder = [[MicrophoneInput alloc] init];

    @try {
        self.config = [GNConfig init:GRACENOTE_CLIENTID];
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"%s clientId can't be nil or the empty string",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
        [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:FALSE];
        return;
    }

    // Debug is disabled in the GUI by default
#ifdef DEBUG
    [self.config setProperty:@"debugEnabled" value:@"1"];
#else
    [self.config setProperty:@"debugEnabled" value:@"0"];
#endif
    [self.config setProperty:@"lookupmodelocalonly" value:@"0"];
}    

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(startRecordMicrophone) withObject:nil];
}

-(void) startRecordMicrophone{
    #ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog(@"%s startRecording",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    #endif
    [self.recorder startRecording];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(makeMyProgressBarMoving) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

-(void) stopRecordMicrophone{
#ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"%s stopRecording",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
#endif
    [self.recorder stopRecording];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = paths[0];
    NSString *filePath =[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"output.caf"];

    NSData* sampleData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        GNSampleBuffer *sampleBuffer = [GNSampleBuffer gNSampleBuffer:sampleData numChannels:1 sampleRate:8000];
    [GNOperations recognizeMIDStreamFromPcm:self config:self.config sampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
}

#pragma mark - UI methods

-(void)makeMyProgressBarMoving {

    float actual = [self.progressBar progress];
    if (actual < 1) {
        [self.loadingAnimationView showNextLevel];
        self.progressBar.progress = actual + 0.0125;
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25f target:self selector:@selector(makeMyProgressBarMoving) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }
    else{
        self.progressBar.hidden = YES;
        [self stopRecordMicrophone];
    }

}            

#pragma mark - GNSearchResultReady methods
- (void) GNResultReady:(GNSearchResult*)result{
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

@end
```

Credits go to Brian Whitman and Echo Nest Library for the MicrophoneInput solution.

Hope it helps someone out who is facing the same situation.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The Gracenote SDK does provide access to the audio data even when using the included GnMic class.  The GnMic class defines a GnMicDelegate protocol, which you can use to get notified when a new audio buffer is available. You must:

**GnViewController.h**

Add the GnMicDelegate protocol to your class definition

```
@interface GnViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UINavigationBarDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, GnMicDelegate>
```

**GnViewController.m**

Assign your class as the delegate for the GnMic instance

```
self.gnMic = [[GnMic alloc] initWithSampleRate: 44100 bitsPerChannel: 16 numberOfChannels: 1 delegate:nil];
self.gnMic.gnMicDelegate = self;
```

Implement the protocol method.  This will get called each time a new audio buffer is available for processing

```
- (void) audioBufferDidBecomeReady:(NSData *)samples {
    // Do something with the audio samples
}
```

Comment: Hi @user2812322, I'm not sure which version you're using but there is not such class on GraceNoteMusicID SDK.

Comment: @PauloMiguelAlmeida Yes, you are correct.  I was referring to a more recent version of the SDK.  But the same functionality is in the version you are using only the class and protocol name is different.  In the version you're using the mic class should be named `GnAudioSourceMic` and the delegate protocol should be named `GNAudioSourceDelegate`.  The implementation with this class and delegate would be the same as in my previous answer.